# How to rotate a 3D plane?

Tags: matlab, math, 3d, rotation

I have a 3d plane (made up of number of points) which is rotated at weird angle. I want to make it flat i.e lie on xy-plane. I have plane equation but I think my calculated angles are not correct or might be using wrong rotation matrix. By wrong rotation matrix is that I meant that I am not sure about which axis should I rotate. attached is the picture of my plane:

[image: this plane is rotated about more then one axis]

I tried to calculate by using following formulas:

1. theta=-acosd((dot(n1,n2))/(norm(n1)*norm(n2)));
2. Calculate spherical angles: theta and phi;

both methods are giving same angle, I rotated my plane first about z-axis and then about y-axis. The resulted plane is almost flat but it still has some anlge.

I tried both rotation matrix and Rodrigues' rotation matrix. It would be really helpful if someone could suggest how to rotate this plane to make it flat.

Comment: If you want a flat plane, you immediately know the plane equation: `z = h`, where `h` is an arbitrary height (the height of the point you would rotate about). What are `n1` and `n2` in your formulas? The two methods should not give the same results as the rotation axes are different.

Comment: Why rotate? You have the plane's normal vector, so it should be a straightforward exercise to find two perpendicular vectors contained in the plane. Use those as the new coordinate basis.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, Thanks for responding. n1=[0 0 1] and n2 is normal to the plane. The formula in 1. and spherical angle theta are giving same value of theta. Could you please explain in detail how to rotate about height??

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis , are you saying that find two  vectors perpendicular to each other lying in the plane? How to use them as the new coordinates? Little more detail will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What I meant is that you don't need to calculate any angle or rotation in order to get a flat plane. Can you provide some more context?

Comment: @NicoSchertler, This plane is a result of a scanner which gave me a 3D point cloud (x, y and z values). My actual plot was a step and I do care about the height of that step. I took out the lower surface of the step and fit to the plane. The plot I showed is the plane fit to that lower surface. I am assuming that if I can make this fitted plane flat, I can apply the same code to my step. I need a flat plane to calculate height of the step. And I will need to do this every time for my other step artifact as well. If you need any other information let me know. Thanks!

Comment: If you know that the plane is flat beforehand, then take this constraint into account when fitting the plane. I.e., all you need to fit is the height of the plane. There is no point in solving a relatively difficult 3D fitting problem when you fix two of the three degrees of freedom afterwards, anyway. Depending on your fitting formulation, the height that you are looking for might just be the average point height.

Answer (score 1):

When a plane is not parallel to the xy-plane, then it's normal vector will not be parallel to the z-axis. So the cross product of the normal vector and the z-axis (unit) vector will be non-zero. This vector is in the plane and parallel to the xy-plane. Take it as rotation axis. The rotation angle to make the plane parallel to the xy-plane is the same as the angle between the normal vector and the z-axis.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I calculated the angle between z-axis and normal to the plane and rotate about x-axis but result is  not correct. What do you mean by rotating about the cross product of normal vector and z-axis (unit) vector?? How can I give rotation about this axis?

Comment: In your example the plane normal is `n = (0.898 -0.443 1)^T`. The cross product with `(0 0 1)^T` is `(0.443 0.898 0)`. This is the axis of rotation, which can be calculated using Rodrigues' rotation matrix.